# How to set up a reward function that includes rewards at each step and overall process performance

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For example, there is an episode s1 a1 s2 a2...sn. At each step, there is a reward ri(i =1, 2,...n) that can be calculated in some fixed way, and the process does not have a terminal state. Each episode ends after a fixed number of rounds. Now I have a problem where, in addition to the reward at each step, I also have a reward associated with the entire process of s1 a1...sn. This reward is important because it is closer to my ultimate task requirement. If there were a clear terminal state like in typical reinforcement learning tasks such as maze navigation or rocket landing, it would be reasonable to add a sparse reward for the final state. However, in my case, it feels unreasonable to add the reward for the entire process as an reward of the episode's final state, considering the final state is random.

To address this situation, what should I do?

How should I set up the reward function that takes into account both the reward of each step and the reward associated with the entire process?

If discussing a specific algorithm, we can discuss within the framework of PPO.